# Exclude '0' values from an Excel 2010 column chart

Tags: excel

Is there any way to exclude values from a chart that are '0'? The data source is a mixture of vlookup's or sums where the results have a value others are '0'. When I plot the chart and there are some axis points with all '0' - can these be excluded to only show columns with data present?

Changing the source data to blank cells stills plots the data. There is an option on the line charts to join/connect empty cells but there is no function that I am aware of for a column chart.

Comment: Hi KamD, and welcome to SO! It is not clear from your question what you are asking. Have a look at this guide, How to ask a good question, then make an edit to your post, and add what you have tried tried

Comment: @NarendraChouhan means to read [ask] then [edit] your question and provide your code as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it is:

Change your formula(s) to an if statement, so that it return NA() instead of 0. The chart won't show/include N/A values, however the label will be viable still as a standard. You may hide this label.

This method will work in this case if I understood your OP correctly. However, it may not work in all cases, as hiding 0-values from graphs may or may not require a different approach.